# Javascript change input values onclick to the value on the same row which the button was clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

let's say if I select floating rate on the third row and I click on the equal sign button. The rest of the value of all the other row will change its value to floating rate. I want to apply tis function to all the other rows too.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       $('.equal').on('click', function() { 
           $('.dropDown').val('Floating Rate'); 
       }) 
   }); 
</script>
```

Table:

```
<td>
<select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_1">
<option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_1'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_1'] ;?></option>
<option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
<option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="button" value="select" class="equal" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_2">
<option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_2'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_2'] ;?></option>
<option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
<option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="button" value="select" class="equal" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_3">
<option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_3'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_3'] ;?></option>
<option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
<option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="button" value="select" class="equal" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_4">
<option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_4'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_4'] ;?></option>
<option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
<option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="button" value="select" class="equal" /></td>
```

Comment: Where is the table? Where is the button? We're missing far too much info here.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stackflow. I just figured out how to place in my codes. Initially I wanted to use $_GET function, But I don't want the page to be refreshed. I'm thinking maybe javascript can achieve the result I want easily. But I'm not familiar with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

in jquery,

```
$('.dropDown').change(function(e) {

//Here you can do you programming
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

for more info,

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: how should I code the button? How do i link it with the option selected and pass it to ths function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropDown").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("#dropDown option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
```

Comment: I wanna use the equal_button.png as the button. So when he select fixed or floating rate on the 3rd row option selection and click on the button at the side of 3rd row. The select option on only the 4th row will become the same value as the 3rd row. If it is from the 2nd row, the 3rd and 4th row will change.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems in there.
First you cannot have id="dropDown" multiple times. Use class="dropDown" instead.
Second, one suggestion is to use a button instead of img.

Here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.equal').on('click', function() {
           $('.dropDown').val('Floating Rate');
       })
   });
</script>
```

And html changes:

```
<select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_1">

<input type="button" value="select" class="equal" />
```

Comment: When I click on the select button nothing changes. Will this work if I select fixed rate instead of floating rate?

Comment: What the above does it on each press on any of the buttons (that have class 'equal'), will select in all drop downs (that have class 'dropDown'), the value 'Floating Rate'. That is what $('.dropDown').val('Floating Rate'); does. Maybe it is smth else you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Psinyee, here is what you want, and also explained.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.equal').on('click', function() {
           // find coresponding dropdown
           // with select inside (this is the button ->parent is the td-> previous td)
           var crtDropdown = $('select', $(this).parent().prev('td'));
           if(crtDropdown.prop('selectedIndex') > 0) {
               // something is selected, not first option
               // change values for following selects
               // select ->parent td->parent tr->all next trs->select inside trs->set val to crtDropdown.val();
               crtDropdown.parent().parent().nextAll('tr').find('select').val(crtDropdown.val());
           }
       })
   });
</script>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_1">
                <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_1'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_1'] ;?></option>
                <option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
                <option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="image" src="equal_button.png" class="equal" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_2">
                <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_2'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_2'] ;?></option>
                <option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
                <option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="image" src="equal_button.png" class="equal" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_3">
                <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_3'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_3'] ;?></option>
                <option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
                <option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="image" src="equal_button.png" class="equal" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="dropDown" style="width:150px" name="rate_value_4">
                <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_4'] ;?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['rate_value_4'] ;?></option>
                <option value="Fixed Rate">Fixed Rate</option>
                <option value="Floating Rate">Floating Rate</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="image" src="equal_button.png" class="equal" /></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```